# Gradient colours in ggplot (relatively simple)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe which I have constructed by interpolating a series of origin destination points (they relate to a cycle share scheme that used to run in Seattle).

I've called the dataframe interpolated_flows:

```
line_id      long      lat seg_num count
1       1 -122.3170 47.61855       1   155
2       1 -122.3170 47.61911       2   155
3       1 -122.3170 47.61967       3   155
4       1 -122.3170 47.62023       4   155
5       1 -122.3169 47.62079       5   155
6       1 -122.3169 47.62135       6   155
```

What I would like to do (and I think is relatively simple if you know ggplot) is to plot these flows (lines) with the width of a line determined by the `count` and the gradient determined by the `seg_num`.

This is my attempt so far:

```
#Create variables to store relevant data for simplicity of code
X <- interpolated_flows$long
Y <- interpolated_flows$lat
sgn <- interpolated_flows$seg_num
ct <- interpolated_flows$count

#Create a map from flow data and include the bounded box as a base
g <- ggplot(interpolated_flows,aes(x=X, y=Y),group=interpolated_flows$line_id,color=sgn)
map <- ggmap(seattle_map,base_layer = g)

map <- map + geom_path(size=as.numeric(ct)/100,alpha=0.4)+
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.03, 0.3))+coord_fixed(ratio=1.3)+
  scale_colour_gradient(high="red",low="blue")

png(filename='Seattle_flows_gradient.png')
print(map)
dev.off()
```

And I end up with the image attached. I have spent a long time playing around with various parameters in the plotting part of the code but without success so would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.[image]

Edit:

```
base <- ggplot(interpolated_flows,aes(x=X, y=Y))
map <- ggmap(seattle_map,base_layer = g)

map <- map+geom_path(aes(color=seg_num,size=as.numeric(count)))+
  scale_size_continuous(name="Journey Count",range=c(0.05,0.4))+
  scale_color_gradient(name="Journey Path",high="white",low="blue",breaks=c(1,10), labels=c('Origin','Destination'))+
  coord_fixed(ratio=1.3)+scale_x_continuous("", breaks=NULL)+
  scale_y_continuous("", breaks=NULL)

png(filename='Seattle_flows_gradient.png')
print(map)
dev.off()
```

This is the plot I have now got to which looks like this. I have only two questions - 1) does anyone know a way to improve the resolution of the background map? I tried changing the `zoom` parameter in the `get_map` function but it didn't seem to help. 2) The lines I have plotted seem very 'white' heavy. It doesn't look to me like the gradient is evenly distributed. Anyone have any ideas why this would be and how to fix?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't remap things out of your original data frame, that's not in line with the `ggplot` methodology, and that's probably why your color mapping isn't working. When you pass `interpolated_flows` as your first `ggplot` argument, that means you can reference columns by their names without using `interpolated_flows$column`, you can just use `column`. So fix that and see if the gradient maps correctly.

Comment: @Mako212 thanks, got you. Today is day 1 of ggplot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this suits you. I have create a new dataset so as to see diffencies. Once the data.frame is created you can use it as your first ggplot argument and reference columns by their names as Mako212 say.

```
long<-seq(-122,-123,length.out = 6)
lat<-seq(47,48,length.out = 6)
seg_num<-seq(1,6,1)
count<-seq(155,165,length.out = 6)

interpolated_flows<-data.frame(long,lat,seg_num,count,stringsAsFactors = false)

base_plot<-ggplot(interpolated_flows,aes(x=long, y=lat))


base_plot+
  geom_path(aes(color=seg_num,size=as.numeric(count/100),alpha=lat))+
  #notice that size, color and alpha are into aethetic 
  scale_size_continuous(name="Count")+
  scale_alpha_continuous(name="Latitude",range = c(0.03, 0.3))+ #you won't need it if you don't want variable transparency
  #just put the desired value into the aethteic
  scale_color_gradient(name="Seg_num",high="red",low="blue")+
  coord_fixed(ratio=1.3)
```

[image: Result]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, super effort. Your answer helped me to get most of the way to where I needed, much appreciated. Hopefully a few others find this useful in future.